# CSS Margin-bottom not working

Tags: css, html, css-float

`margin-bottom: 30px;`
 is not working on the `.box` class. I'm trying to add a bit of extra space under the box but its not working. 
How can I fix this? Here is my HTML.  is there anything else that I should change in the code? to make it better.

Here is my HTML. . . .

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>
    <title>web</title>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="nav" class="navi"> <a class="navi" href="#"> Link </a>
                <a class="navi" href="#"> Link </a>
                <a class="navi" href="#"> Link </a>
                <a class="navi" href="#"> Link </a>
                <a class="navi" href="#"> Link </a>
                <a class="navi" href="#"> Link </a>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div class="box">
                     <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>

                     <h2>Sub heading</h2>
                    <p>dolor sit amet, epicurei neglegentur sit an, libris numquam ius ei. Appareat volutpat imperdiet no vim, ut suas aliquid sanctus quo. At duo quot essent suscipit. Vis an atomorum accusamus. Est at nemore ponderum. No nec voluptua conceptam, detraxit splendide disputando nam ea. Ne eum vocibus inimicus democritum, erant praesent eam in, agam ludus verterem an pro. Erant vidisse te vel, vim ei summo honestatis, no libris quidam inermis quo. Blandit sententiae no per. Ullum accumsan praesent usu ut, at usu verterem sententiae. Accumsan signiferumque et sit, id audiam patrioque vix. Ei accusam electram theophrastus eos, sea solet epicuri molestiae ad. No sanctus scriptorem vim. Simul voluptaria scripserit cu his, perfecto petentium cotidieque cu duo. Te mei case ullum assum, mei te sint fugit. Ut minim albucius invenire est, at nec sint utroque. Ei cum legimus fastidii democritum, sit expetenda gubergren ex. Ex dolorem scripserit has, sit in tation theophrastus. Sed veri viderer te, eos porro feugiat ut, mel sanctus impedit phaedrum id. No sit dicant denique adipisci, habemus scaevola mei ne, qui no solum idque verterem. Mei ut etiam everti atomorum. Vis ex tibique appetere, ei sed tota aperiri scripserit. Mei verterem antiopam constituam an, id quodsi tibique quo, detracto iudicabit similique ex his. Graece vocibus mediocrem no pri, cu odio suas his. Sea in fabulas oportere adversarium, eu eos quodsi latine fabellas.</p>
                    <<p>dolor sit amet, epicurei neglegentur sit an, libris numquam ius ei. Appareat volutpat imperdiet no vim, ut suas aliquid sanctus quo. At duo quot essent suscipit. Vis an atomorum accusamus. Est at nemore ponderum. No nec voluptua conceptam, detraxit splendide disputando nam ea. Ne eum vocibus inimicus democritum, erant praesent eam in, agam ludus verterem an pro. Erant vidisse te vel, vim ei summo honestatis, no libris quidam inermis quo. Blandit sententiae no per. Ullum accumsan praesent usu ut, at usu verterem sententiae. Accumsan signiferumque et sit, id audiam patrioque vix. Ei accusam electram theophrastus eos, sea solet epicuri molestiae ad. No sanctus scriptorem vim. Simul voluptaria scripserit cu his, perfecto petentium cotidieque cu duo. Te mei case ullum assum, mei te sint fugit. Ut minim albucius invenire est, at nec sint utroque. Ei cum legimus fastidii democritum, sit expetenda gubergren ex. Ex dolorem scripserit has, sit in tation theophrastus. Sed veri viderer te, eos porro feugiat ut, mel sanctus impedit phaedrum id.</p>
                         <h1>Extras</h1>

                        <p>No sanctus scriptorem vim. Simul voluptaria scripserit cu his, perfecto petentium cotidieque cu duo. Te mei case ullum assum, mei te sint fugit. Ut minim albucius invenire est, at nec sint utroque. Ei cum legimus fastidii democritum, sit expetenda gubergren ex. Ex dolorem scripserit has, sit in tation theophrastus. Sed veri viderer te, eos porro feugiat ut, mel sanctus impedit phaedrum id.</p>h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                         <h2>Sub heading</h2>

                        <p>No sanctus scriptorem vim. Simul voluptaria scripserit cu his, perfecto petentium cotidieque cu duo. Te mei case ullum assum, mei te sint fugit. Ut minim albucius invenire est, at nec sint utroque. Ei cum legimus fastidii democritum, sit expetenda gubergren ex. Ex dolorem scripserit has, sit in tation theophrastus. Sed veri viderer te, eos porro feugiat ut, mel sanctus impedit phaedrum id.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

</html>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS. . .

```
body {
     background: url(images/heart.jpg) bottom left no-repeat fixed;
     margin-bottom: 100px;
     background-color:#c4c2c9;
 }
 #
     text-transform:uppercase;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family:"Times new Roman";
     padding-left: 40px;
     color:#FFFFFF;
     text-decoration:none;
 }
 A:hover.navi {
     color:#FFFFFF;
     text-decoration:underline;
 }
 A:visited.navi {
     color:#FFFFFF;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-size: 12px;
 }
 p {
     word-spacing:3px;
     font-size: 12px;
     color:#050505;
     font-family:"Times new Roman";
 }
 p2 {
     word-spacing:3px;
     font-size: 12px;
     color:#050505;
     font-family:"Times new Roman";
 }
 h1 {
     text-transform:uppercase;
     color:#050505;
     font-family:"Times New Roman";
     letter-spacing:10px;
     font-size: 19px;
 }
 h2 {
     text-transform:uppercase;
     color:#050505;
     padding-bottom: 3px;
     border-bottom: solid 2px #d7d7d7;
     font-family:"Times New Roman";
     letter-spacing:10px;
     font-size: 9px;
 }
 a:link {
     color:##050505;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-size: 12px;
 }
 a:visited {
     color:##050505;
     text-decoration:none;
 }
 a:hover {
     color:#050505;
     text-decoration:underline;
 }
 a:active {
     color:#050505;
     text-decoration:none;
 }
```

Comment: Hi user, welcome to Stack Overflow. You might try putting together a demo here on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: way too much positioning has been used in your case....try creating a layout using floats, margins, paddings & and if necessary, play with positioning.

Comment: is the absolute position in the nav and content really necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because your `.box` was positioned absolute and to add extra bit of space try adjusting the `padding-bottom:`

Answer (score 0):

Add a div with class `.height` and give height:30px to it instead of adding `margin-bottom:30px`

```
            <div id="content">
                <div class="box">
                     <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>YOUR CONTENT</p>
                <div class="height"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Css:

```
.height {
    height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin-bottom` needs an element to bounce on in act to work. I made an example to explain it, try it [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CRBCX/). You'll see that when you a paragraph, that then the first paragraph does have a margin-bottom, but without an element under it it doesn't.

You can solve it to add a padding-bottom to the parent element [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/CRBCX/2/).